# How to find file extension in Azure Storage?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure

If there is no extension in the file name, then I cannot get the `contentType` to create `FileStreamResult`.
    Example:

```
byte[] byteFile = await someDirectory.GetFileContentAsync(fileName);    
string contentType; 
new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(fileName, out contentType); // fileName without extension
return (byteFile, contentType); // contentType == null
```

Is there a way to get the extension not from the name?

Comment: You want to get azure blob file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code for [`FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs), there's a predefined list of file extensions and their corresponding mime-types. `TryGetContentType` method will return `null` if the file extension is not in that list.

If you get a file without file extension, one possible way would be to find the kind of file by reading it's metadata but that's really complicated. For example, reading the file contents you can find out if the file is an image and if it is of type png. But you will need to write code to identify each type of image (png, bmp, gif etc.).

A simpler way would be to infer `null` content type as default content type. In case of Azure Storage, it will be `application/octet-stream`.